# Are there polynomials $p(x)$ such that $p(\sin x)=\sin(2x)$ for all $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polynomials

Are there any polynomials $p(x)$ such that $$p(\sin x)= \sin (2x)\;\;\;\;\; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\,?$$

---

This is what i did: Anyway, thanks for your hint, I think I've found the solution. Here's my reasoning: we would have $|p(t)|=2t\sqrt{1−t^2}$, $\forall t\in\mathbb{R}$, so for the identity principle $|p(t)|=2t\sqrt{1−t^2}$ but this is not a polynomial. Is it right?

Comment: Have you applied the identity $\sin(2x) = 2\sin x \cos x$? $\qquad$

Comment: Questions posted here should not be phrased in language suitable for assigning homework. That's almost certainly the reason why someone voted to close this question. They ought to explain that here in comments under the question, but usually they don't.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose there is. Then we have $p(x)$ such that

$$ (p(\sin x))^2 = 4\sin^2 x (1-\sin^2 x)$$

put $t=\sin x$ then we have $$p(t)^2 = \underbrace{4t^2(1-t^2)}_{q(t)};\;\;\;\;\;\;\forall t\in[-1,1]$$

So $p(t)^2$ and $q(t)$ match for infinite values so they match for all values. So $p(t)$ is of second degree, so $p(t)= at^2+bt+c$ and $a\ne 0$. Now we have

$$ a^2t^4+2abt^3+(2ac+b^2)t^2+2bct+c^2 = -4t^4+4t^2$$ so we have $a^2=-4m$, $2ab=0$, $2ac+b^2 =4$ and $c=0$. From second equation we get $b=0$ and from second $b=\pm 2$, so there is no such polynomial.

Comment: You can also note that $t=0$, $t=-1$, and $t=+1$ are roots of $p(t)$, so $p(t)$ is divisible by $t(t+1)(t-1)$.  Furthermore, $p(t)$ is nonzero.  Thus, $p(t)$ is of degree at least $3$, but $\big(p(t)\big)^2=4t^2(1-t^2)$ is of degree $4\neq 2\cdot 3$, which is absurd.

Comment: I did not understand - "...So $p(t)^2$ and $q(t)$ match for infinite values so they match for all values..". Can you explain?

Comment: If two polynomials of a degree $n$ match in $n+1$ values then they match for all values (they are the same polynomial)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest approach I can think of is to note that
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)$$
but
$$\sin\left(2\cdot\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\neq \sin\left(2\cdot\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\,.$$
This means: not only there does not exist a polynomial function $p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $p\big(\sin(x)\big)=\sin(2x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, but you also know that there does not exist any function $p:[-1,+1]\to\mathbb{R}$ at all, polynomial or not, that satisfies $p\big(\sin(x)\big)=\sin(2x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplification of greedoid's answer, assuming $p$ is a real polynomial.

We have $p(t)^2=4t^2(1-t^2)=q(t)$ for all $t\in[-1,1]$ and so for all $t \in \mathbb R$. But then
$$
0 \le p(2)^2 = q(2) = -12 < 0,
$$ a contradiction.

Comment: How do you know $p(2)^2\geq 0$?

Comment: This shows that there does not exist $p(t)\in\mathbb{R}[t]$ with the required condition.  But it doesn't show whether there exists $p(t)\in\mathbb{C}[t]$ that works, though.  The OP did not say anything about the coefficients of $p(t)$, so I don't know.

Comment: From the givens you just have $p^2(t)=4t^2(1-t^2)=q(t)$ for $-1\leq t\leq1$. As $p$ is a polynomial this implies that $p^2(t)=q(t)$ for all $t\in{\mathbb R}$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove a more general result which states the only polynomial satisfying $P(\sin x)=P(\sin 2x)$ is the constant polynomial.

First we observe the sequence $\sin(\pi/2^n),\sin(\pi/2^{n-1}),\sin(\pi/2^{n-2}),...,\sin(\pi/2)$ are $n$ distinct numbers in an increasing order as $\sin x$ is monotonic on $[0, pi/2]$.
If there exists such non-constant polynomial, by the assumption, we have
$P(\sin(\pi/2^n))=P(\sin(\pi/2^{n-1})=P(\sin(\pi/2^{n-2})=...=P(\sin(\pi/2))$,by applying the MVT, we can construct $n-1$ distinct numbers(let's call them $a_i$) s.t.
$P'(a_i)=0$, where $\sin(\pi/2^i)<a_i<\sin(\pi/2^{i+1}), 1\le i<n$. Which means the degree of polynomial $P'(x)$ is greater than or equal to $n-1$, which gives the degree of $P(x)$ is greater than or equal to $n$. However, the choice of $n$ is arbitrary, hence we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, similar to Batominovski’s answer, we have that

$$p\left(\frac \pi 4\right)= p\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}2\right)=\sin \left(\frac \pi 2\right)=1$$

but

$$p\left(\frac {3\pi}4\right)= p\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}2\right)=\sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }2\right)=-1$$

therefore no polynomial nor function defined on $\mathbb R$ exists with such property.